# How to solve merge conflict in a approved review in gerrit?

Tags: git-merge, gerrit, merge-conflict-resolution

I made a change in gerrit which was code reviewed and after 7 revisions approved. But, now it cannot be merged and trying to rebase in gerrit website is not working due to merge conflict. How can I resolve this merge conflict and merge the same approved change and not create a new one. 
(Full steps from cloning the repo  would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1) Clone the Gerrit repository

```
git clone https://USER@GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-FULL-PATHNAME
```

2) Go to the change page on Gerrit and copy the checkout patch command

```
git fetch https://USER@GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-FULL-PATHNAME refs/changes/XX/YYYYY/Z && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

3) Rebase the change

```
git rebase origin/BRANCH
```

4) Solve the conflicts

```
git mergetool
```

5) Continue the rebase

```
git rebase --continue
```

Repeat the steps 4 and 5 until the end of conflicts

```
git commit --amend
```

Note: Keep the same Change-Id

6) Send the new patchset to Gerrit

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/BRANCH
```

Comment: Tip for readers: If you already have a repo and don't want to git clone again, you can use 'git fetch' to replace the first command.

Comment: Actually, if you already have a repo you can just skip the first step. The "git fetch" will already be executed in step 2.

Comment: I think you missed `git add .` after `git mergetool`. You need to do it before `git rebase --continue`

Comment: I think "git add" is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution works but I personally disagree with this workflow. It is unnecessarily cumbersome.

I prefer a workflow with exactly one merge and therefore less steps.

1. Clone the Gerrit repository if not already available

   ```
   git clone https://[USER]@[GERRIT-SERVER]/a/[REPO-FULL-PATHNAME]
   ```
2. Checkout the Gerrit patch

   ```
   git fetch https://[USER]@[GERRIT-SERVER]/a/[REPO-FULL-PATHNAME] refs/changes/46/12346/N && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
   ```
3. Soft-reset the change and stash it

   ```
   git reset --soft HEAD~1 && git stash
   ```
4. Checkout branch or the Gerrit patch you want to rebase onto

   ```bash
   git checkout origin/BRANCH
   # or fetch other Gerrit patch:
   # git fetch https://[USER]@[GERRIT-SERVER]/a/[REPO-FULL-PATHNAME] refs/changes/45/12345/N && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
   ```
5. Unstash the previously stashed changes

   ```
   git stash pop
   ```
6. Solve the conflicts with your favourite 3-way merge tool.
7. Commit the merged changes - NOT (!!) amend them - and use the same Change-Id from the merged patch in the message:

   ```bash
   git commit -am "[COMMIT-MESSAGE]\
   \
   Change-Id: [FORMER-CHANGE-ID]"
   ```
8. Send the new patchset to Gerrit

   ```
   git push origin HEAD:refs/for/BRANCH
   ```

Done. One merge!

---

I additionally use the gitreview tool. That makes it extra easy. Steps 2, 3, 4 and 5 then can be chained.

```
git review -d 12346 && git reset --soft HEAD~1 && git stash && git review -d 12345 && git stash pop
```