# Gerrit UI showing status as merge conflict even when there is no conflict

Tags: git, gerrit, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

One of my outgoing review was showing merge conflict (not submitted, in process). I fetched the latest from master and then merged that with my feature branch and updated my change list on gerrit. But it is still showing merge conflict.

I have looked into the files and I have grepped the whole directory for ***<<<<<<< HEAD*** . But I could not find any conflict.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I  have looked into the files

Those would be your files locally, which haven't been merged.

As in "[How to solve merge conflict in a approved review in gerrit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53213237/6309)", fetch the changeset, rebase it locally onto `origin/<yourBranch>`: you should see conflicts there.

The idea is to resolve conflicts locally, then push back the modified changeset.

Comment: Yes, I fetched the changeset, merged my local branch with master, resolved conflict and then pushed it. But still it is showing the same merge conflict as status.

Comment: @imox I don't think a merge is recommended here: only a rebase. And a rebase to an up-to-date master.

Comment: thanks for your comment. do you mean not recommended and will not work? can you please tell me why? What options do I have now to remove the merge conflict?

Comment: @imox Try and follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209237/how-to-solve-merge-conflict-in-a-approved-review-in-gerrit/53213237#53213237, which shows a  rebase.

Comment: Looking into it. but my review is in process and not approved.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem some days ago. In my case, after merging I have made `git reset --soft HEAD~` which transfered my changes from "commited" to "staged". Then I have commited them again and it worked. It was strange behavior but it is never happened again.