# Resolve merge conflict in gerrit/git

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

At work we use gerrit for codereview and as a git server. Also we have the following workflow:

1. For each feature create a new feature branch
2. If feature is ready, push it to `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature` for codereview
3. After codereview, submit your change and merge origin/feature in your local master: `git checkout master && git merge --no-ff origin/feature`
4. After resolving all conflicts push it a second time to gerrit `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`
5. If the change from step 4 is okay, submit it.

Problem: Lets say everything works smooth until step 5. My change was reviewed and I´m ready to submit the change. In the meantime another developer pushes some changes directly to master. Gerrit gives me now a "merge conflict" in my change without the option to submit my change.

Now i´m a little bit lost in how I should resolve this issue...at the moment I can only come up with the following three solutions:

1. Checkout the change and `git rebase origin/master` (losing my previous merge commit, rewriting history)
2. Checkout the change and `git rebase --rebase-merges origin/master` (rewriting history)
3. Checkout the change and 'git merge --no-ff origin/master' (history is a little bit f*cked up...)

Is there a safe and elegen solution to this problem ? How would you solve it ? I´m quite new to git/gerrit and dont want to mess up our repo...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git-repository)

Comment: Not rly. I know how to resolve merge conflicts in git ^^

Comment: Then I didn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Did you already read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209237/how-to-solve-merge-conflict-in-a-approved-review-in-gerrit/53213237

Comment: Do you know how gerrit works ?

Comment: Rewriting history would be frustrating. So I think the 3rd way is better. To make the history look clean, you could also merge `feature` to the latest `master` again. If you find resolving conflicts repeatedly annoying, you could enable `git rerere`.

Comment: I used the third solution. Went way smoother than with rebasing ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a workflow that relies on rebasing. That is, your solution 1.

I would also recommend periodically rebasing to HEAD between steps 1 and 2 during development to minimize surprises at review time.

Generally this makes it easier to understand the change as a simple application of your commits. I find it is generally much easier from the perspective of the reviewer too, and also for everyone to reason about should there ever be a need to roll back a change.

Comment: Can you think of any implications with solution 2 ? Usually I dont want to throw away the merge commit...

Comment: I guess I'm mostly a fan of leaving a clear trail of what **actually** happened at HEAD. The cost of discarding some transient info that doesn't contribute to understanding the actual history of the committed HEAD is mostly a win as I see it. That is, less of a cognitive burden to those looking back at how things got to where they ended up.